# Trying to get my menu to show after clicking on the hamburger menu. Hamburger Menu shows on a certain width

Tags: html, css, responsive

When the screen is a certain size the nav list then becomes hidden and there is a menu being shown.

When you click the hamburger its supposed to display the menu and when you click the X its suppose to close the menu.

I am getting every effect except the menu showing in the drop down list.

codepen to view code

https://codepen.io/mattmatt33/project/editor/DQpvPP#0

HTML and CSS:

```css
/* Hamburger Menu Start */

.menu-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: #fff; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

/* hamburger lines */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--mainColor);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* top and bottom lines */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: inherit;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div:after {
    top: 10px;
}

/* Turn lines into an X */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}


.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Hamburger Menu End */

@media (max-width: 1024px ) {
    .nav-list {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .nav-list {
        display: block; 
        margin-top: 70px;
        margin-left: 63%;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .menu-wrap {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .nav-list {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    
     .main-logo {
        max-width: 100%;
    } 
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
   
    .main-logo {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<header>
            
        <a href="home.html"> <img src="../imgs/logo.jpg" alt="Kreative Kage Logo" class="main-logo"> </a>
            
        <div class="menu-wrap">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
                        <div class="hamburger">
                            <div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <ul class="nav-list"> 
                    <a href="home.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a href="gallery.html"><li>Gallery

                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <a href="weddings.html"><li>Weddings</li></a>
                            <a href="maternity.html"><li>Maternity</li></a>
                            <a href="seniors.html"><li>Graduates</li></a>
                            <a href="babies.html"><li>New Borns</li></a>
                            <a href="family.html"><li>Family</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </li></a>
                    <a href="photographers.html"><li>Photographers
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <a href="omar.html"><li>Jordan Kage</li></a>
                                    <a href="dave.html"><li>Dave Kage</li></a>
                                    <a href="jas.html"><li>Jas</li></a>
                            </ul>
                    </li></a>
                    <a href="rates.html"><li>Rates</li></a>
                    <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
                </ul>
            
        </header>
```

Comment: Can you put your working codes inside an online editor like https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mattmatt33/project/editor/DQpvPP#0

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use jquery/js? If you add something like `$('.menu-wrap').click(function(){
   $('.nav-list').toggle();
});` it should solve the issue, make sure u remove the ` visibility: hidden`

Comment: Im not really good at JS. Does that work?

Comment: remove the visibility: hidden from where? I believe its in there a lot .

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is not correctly selecting the `.nav-list` element

```
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .nav-list {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

> The element1~element2 selector matches occurrences of element2 that are preceded by element1.
>
> Both elements must have the same parent, but element2 does not have to
>   be immediately preceded by element1.

The `.nav-list` element is a sibling of `.menu-wrap` not a child.

There's no way in CSS for `.nav-list` to be aware of the state of `.toggler`. The easiest solution is to use JavaScript to apply a `.checked` class to `.menu-wrap` and add this CSS to make the menu visible when the hamburger is clicked:

```
.menu-wrap.checked > .nav-list {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more please? Am I adding the class through JS and then making the change in CSS or am I making all of the changes thru JS?

Comment: You'll replace your current css for .menu-wrap .toggler:checked with the .menu-wrap.checked css I wrote above. Then you'll use JS to toggle the .checked class on the .menu-wrap element.

Comment: Ok so I got the menu to show on click with JS but now I can't remove it on click, I even tried a reset method. Maybe Im using the reset() in the wrong place. Can u help please?                                                                                                             let nav = document.querySelector('.nav-list');

        menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
        nav.style.visibility = 'visible';
        });

    
        menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
            menu.reset();
        nav.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        });

Comment: @MattGeiter I wouldn't alter the nav element's style directly in the Javascript. Just define your styles in the CSS like I did above. Then toggle the '.checked' class on and off like this 
`const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-list');
menu.addEventListener('click', function() { nav.classList.toggle('checked')' })`
Reference this [W3 lesson](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

Comment: I dont know what I am doing different but its not working at all `<script>
        
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-list');
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu-wrap');

    menu.classList.add('checked');
    

    menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
        nav.classList.toggle('checked');
    });
        
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was talking about. Please look at the bottom CSS to see the changes. I also have question on your `media query`, why don't you start from the smallest size up (mobile to desktop) setup with `min-width` instead of `max-width`. What happen to your elements when the screen is > 1024px? There's no default setup

```js
$('.menu-wrap').click(function(){ $('.nav-list').toggle(); });
```

```css
/* Hamburger Menu Start */

.menu-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #000; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

/* hamburger lines */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* top and bottom lines */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: inherit;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger > div:after {
    top: 10px;
}

/* Turn lines into an X */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Hamburger Menu End */

/*CHANGES MADE HERE*/
.nav-list {
    display: none; 
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 63%;
}
.menu-wrap {
    visibility: visible;
}  
 .main-logo {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
            
        <a href="home.html"> Logo </a>           
        <div class="menu-wrap">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
                        <div class="hamburger">
                            <div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <ul class="nav-list"> 
                    <a href="home.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a href="gallery.html"><li>Gallery

                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <a href="weddings.html"><li>Weddings</li></a>
                            <a href="maternity.html"><li>Maternity</li></a>
                            <a href="seniors.html"><li>Graduates</li></a>
                            <a href="babies.html"><li>New Borns</li></a>
                            <a href="family.html"><li>Family</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </li></a>
                    <a href="photographers.html"><li>Photographers
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <a href="omar.html"><li>Jordan Kage</li></a>
                                    <a href="dave.html"><li>Dave Kage</li></a>
                                    <a href="jas.html"><li>Jas</li></a>
                            </ul>
                    </li></a>
                    <a href="rates.html"><li>Rates</li></a>
                    <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
                </ul>
            
        </header>
```